# Curl: Connection Refused Even When Application Is Running

Tags: ubuntu

I created a .net core MVC application and tried to run it on Ubuntu server. I changed the default port from 5000 to 6001. When I run it on Ubuntu and try to curl localhost:6001 , I get a message "Connection refused on port 6001. When I query nestat and grep 6001 , I get no response or feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my situation by first using "wget localhost:6001" and i had a message that the ssl certificate is invalid. So i change my .net urls to use only http and it work for me.